# Multiple notifications

Tags: notifications, gmail

This started with the latest update about a month ago. It first started with getting no notifications. Now i get multiple notifications for each email. They used to be grouped together.  Samsung s23. One email account, one app.

Comment: Possibly related/dupe: [Why am I getting a separate notification for each incoming e-mail?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/255360/44325) (not answered yet)